# How to input half-width characters with mozc-fcitx input method in LInux?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question in a few places but nobody replied. I'm not sure if Japanese SE is the right place to ask but I'll give it a try.

In Linux I input Japanese with `mozc-fcitx`. However, I don't seem to find any way to configure it. By default, full-width characters are entered, which affect even spaces. Is there a way to configure `mozc-fcitx` to input half-width characters by default?

Comment: The right place would probably be [Super User](http://superuser.com/), I think, but we've been allowing this sort of question on our meta site.  That's not really what meta is supposed to be for, but as long as our community wants to use our meta this way, we can keep allowing this sort of question.

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/169835/where-are-mozc-settings

Comment: Since you are running Linux, I think the right place would be https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @QING Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Yeah I tried to ask it in unix.stackexchange.com but got no reply.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Qing, the command `/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog` launches mozc settings. It's not well integrated into the `ibus` or `fcitx` UI though and thus is hard to find.